# What is the "Safe Center" in Android 6.0?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, background-process

On my non-rooted Android 6.0, there is an "Safe Center" in System Settings.

[image]

Clicking on it opens "Background app management" which has features for restricting apps:

[image]

I've not seen such setting/feature before in previous versions of Android. So, I want to know what the "Safe Center" is and How it works.

Comment: This is not a native Android M feature. What's the brand/model of your Android device?

Comment: @AndyYan Lenovo A6600 PLUS

Comment: I don't own Lenovo device but going by the description in the second screen slot, it is very much like *Stamina Mode of Sony* or *protected apps of Huawei*. It is a battery saving feature.You can read about them [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/152649/131553) and confirm if correct

Comment: In addition it seems to prevent selected apps from auto starting on power on, thereby reducing boot time and RAM usage