# Some apps do not display notifications when closed

Tags: notifications

I have a Huawei Y536A1 (Huawei Fusion 3) on Android 4.4.3, and I'm having an issue with some apps not giving notifications when they aren't opened, but apps like YouTube and Skype (sometimes) giving notifications even when they're closed. I checked my notification manager and all apps are set to allowed. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Possibly related https://android.stackexchange.com/q/152649/131553

Comment: @beeshyams I have protected apps, and even with some apps enabled (like an app that replaces the home button), it still closes

Comment: Is it because of *doze* feature in Android 6.0 and above? Check if those affected apps are excluded from doze. I don't know, what the equivalent of doze is in Huawei. Protected apps feature was there before doze

Comment: @beeshyams it's android 4.4.3

Comment: Sorry, missed that part in the question.  I have no further ideas. All the best