# Delayed notifications on Huawei Mate 10 pro with Android Pie, EMUI 9.0

Tags: notifications, huawei, 9.0-pie

What I experience these last months is that notifications from various apps of mine  do not appear in time.

Either they appear very late or not at all (until I open the specific app).

My system is Huawei Mate 10 pro with Android Pie, EMUI 9.0.

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely reason is battery saving feature of Huawei which is a stronger version of [doze-mode](/questions/tagged/doze-mode), in that apps are frozen if inactive after a duration. I had seen this on my earlier Huawei device. See my answer here. [What is protected apps in Huawei phones?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/152649/131553).

It looks like it is not called "protected apps" anymore and this [Reddit](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjdgZm5hu7gAhUM7IMKHSuADtsQzPwBCAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FAndroidQuestions%2Fcomments%2F9xq827%2Fhuawei_mate_20_pro_killing_background_apps_all%2F&psig=AOvVaw27aP25wEYCvb_5tRrPIuPb&ust=1551980073870409) explains the required settings to disable this for apps. There is also a feature of *Power Genius* involved and a workaround to bypass that. Options mentioned in Reddit

> See if you can find a way to turn off battery savings in this Location or similar Settings- apps & notifications - apps- settings cog- special access - ignore battery optimisation >allow/disallow

Or

> Settings -> Apps -> Apps -> three dots on upper right corner -> special access -> battery optimization -> change dropdown menu to "all apps" -> change apps you want to keep in background to "don't allow, may drain battery more quickly

**Edit:** OP confirmed that the second option was the right one for their device. Thanks

Disable battery saving feature for those apps and hopefully that should fix delayed notifications.